# Google me ha suspendido una app

Tags: android, servicio, google-play

Google me ha suspendido una aplicación porque dice que tiene un comportamiento malicioso. La aplicación ejecuta un servicio en segundo plano enviando la posición geográfica a un bbdd remota para que el resto de los usuarios del grupo familiar puedan consultarlo. ¿Que puedo hacer? ¿Cómo lo hace Life360?

Me dice lo siguiente:

Problema: Violación de la política de comportamiento malintencionado. No permitimos aplicaciones que roben datos, monitoreen en secreto o dañen a los usuarios, o que sean maliciosos. Hemos determinado que esta aplicación se está promoviendo como un medio de espionaje o vigilancia secreta de otros.

La vigilancia y el "spyware comercial" están explícitamente prohibidos en Google Play. Solo las aplicaciones que cumplan con las políticas, diseñadas y comercializadas exclusivamente para la supervisión de los padres (incluida la familia) o la gestión empresarial, pueden distribuirse en Google Play con funciones de seguimiento e informes, siempre que cumplan con estos requisitos ...

Comment: Cambia el tipo de app - familiar etc, y anuncia lo que hace - que envía datos de geolocalizaación.

Comment: Si que hay un apartado en la consola de desarrollador para indicar que es familiar, probaré por esa vía a ver si me permiten subirla. Es una pena que después de tanto trabajo no pueda verla en la tienda.

Comment: @EvgeniEnchev Pues no me lo permite, ya que siendo familiar debe de ir dirigido a menores y a estos no se le puede pedir permisos de ubicación según la política de las apps destinadas a las familias. Pues sinceramente, no sé que me estoy perdiendo. Como lo hacen App como safe365, Life360 y demás?

Answer (score 1):

La aplicación fue suspendida precisamente por lo que comentas:

> "La aplicación ejecuta un servicio en segundo plano enviando la
>   posición geográfica a un bbdd remota para que el resto de los usuarios
>   del grupo familiar puedan consultarlo."

Esto es independiente a la [clasificación definida para tu aplicación](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/188189?hl=es-419) por lo tanto esto no es la solución para volver a habilitarla.

En realidad no debes ocultar el proceso que realiza tu aplicación, **debes usar las [APIs y clases del Android SDK](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current#permissions) para obtener la geolocalización requiriendo los permisos e indicando al usuario si quiere compartir si geolocalización, el usuario debe aceptar manualmente esta funcionalidad.**

Si vas a almacenar datos se sugiere usar como base de datos [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore?hl=es-419)

De otra forma tu aplicación sera considerada maliciosa y será dada de baja, ya que Google indica:

> No permitimos aplicaciones que roben datos, **monitoreen** o dañen **a los
>   usuarios de forma secreta** o que sean maliciosos.

[Privacidad, seguridad y engaño](https://play.google.com/about/privacy-security-deception/malicious-behavior/)

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Desde el principio estaba pidiendo permisos de ubicación en tiempo de ejecución. Osea que el usuario debe de con cederlos para que pueda usar la App. Después de varias apelaciones me dieron a entender que era la descripción de la Ficha de la Play Store, que según me dijeron que la describí como una App de espionaje. Nada más lejos. En todo momento sabes que hace la la app, como he dicho, no puedes utilizarla si no aceptas los permisos. Finalmente me dijeron que modificará la descripción y nombre de paquete y la volviera a subir. https://play.google.com/store/apps/deta

Comment: Perdón, este es finalmente el enlace: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=como.sgm.apolo  se puede buscar como localizador familiar Apolo. De momento está...

Comment: Estas usando las clasesn de geolocalización de Google? Si esta definida como "familiar" o no, esto no tiene que ver aquí.

Comment: Sí, estoy usando la geolocalización de Google